# Phred qual error after fastq trimming with Cutadapt

Tags: mapping, trim

I would like to trim the beginning of all the reads in fastq file by a given length, before mapping to the genome with bowtie2. I have used Cutadapt:

```
cutadapt -u 48 -o output.fastq.gz input.fastq.gz
```

my fastq files after trimming looks like this:

```
gunzip -c output.fastq.gz | head

@NB502143:99:HFF7TAFX2:1:11101:4133:1019 1:N:0:ATCACG
CATGAAAAAGAGCTCATTTTCAGATGCAGGAATTCCTATCCG
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@NB502143:99:HFF7TAFX2:1:11101:19790:1020 1:N:0:ATCACG
CATGATCCACTTTTCCACGCGCTTTGACGACCATTTTATAA
+
EEEEE<EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE<EE/EEAEEEEEEEEEEE
@NB502143:99:HFF7TAFX2:1:11101:6327:1020 1:N:0:ATCACG
CATGATCTCAGTAAAGGCATTTGTGGTTGTTAAGTAGCCATT
```

When I try to map it with bowtie2, I get the following error message:

```
Saw ASCII character 10 but expected 33-based Phred qual.
```

I don't get this error if I map input.fastq.gz, so I suspect something wrong is happening during the trimming but I can't figure out what!
I checked both files with FastQC and they're both Sanger / Illumina 1.9 encoded.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar issue. The error occurs when I use `cutadapt`, but does not happen when I trim with another tool, `fastp`.

Checking the integrity of the resulting trimmed `fastq` files showed that some reads had no bases. A tool like `fastq_info` from the [fastq_utils](https://github.com/nunofonseca/fastq_utils) package would work.

If there is an issue, you might need to use the `-m <minimum-length>` flag when running `cutadapt`. This will remove reads below a designated length. Alignment after that should work if that was the issue.